# CryptographyDeprecationWarning:

Tags: python-2.7

Me encontre con este error al momento de ejecutar una instalación:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29
Attaching to
```

---

este es mi log de error
my log
kobo@www:~/kobo-install$ ./run.py --logs
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29
WARNING: Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 29

Answer (score 0):

El mismo error te está indicando el problema. Python2 ya no se soporta y deberías dejar de usarlo. Usa la versión 3.6 o superior de python ya que la mayoría de librerías no tendrán soporte para python2.